# Why do cross_val_predict and cross_val_score not use the same datastructure for cv?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I split my dataset manually into 3 Folds. Using these folds on cross_val_score works just fine, but using these folds with cross_val_predict returns:

> "ValueError: cross_val_predict only works for partitions"

or

> "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

depending on the datastructure I use.

I already tried to switch from sklearn 0.17.1 to 0.20.2 which did not help. The first Exception is returned when the type of the kfolds is `list` when I convert it into a numpy.array I get the second Exception. What I don't understand, is that the documentation for cross_val_score and cross_val_predict say that the argument "cv" needs:

> - None, to use the default 3-fold cross validation,
> - integer, to specify the number of folds in a (Stratified) KFold,
> - CV splitter,
> - An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices.

How are lists and numpy.array no iterables? 
What datastructure should I use?

```
def custom_folds(file_names, class_len, aug):
    # ...
    # ...
    # ...
    '''
    here the indices from the whole dataset are retrievd
    the directories of the folds only provide the names of the data to use in each fold, since the data in the other directories will be processed differently
    '''
    for fold in sorted(os.listdir(folds_path)):
        training = []
        test = []
        fold_path = os.path.join(folds_path, fold)
        set_list = sorted(os.listdir(fold_path))
        for set_type in set_list:
            set_path = os.path.join(fold_path, set_type)
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(set_path):
                if set_type == 'training':
                    [training.append(x) for x in files]
                if set_type in ['test', 'validation']:
                    [test.append(x) for x in files]
        train_idx = [file_names.index(x) for x in file_names if x in training]
        test_idx = [file_names.index(x) for x in file_names if x in test]
        folds.append((train_idx, test_idx))
    return folds

def cross_val(X, y, estimator, aug):
    num_class = len(list(set(y)))
    kfold = custom_folds(file_names, num_class, aug)
    # cross_val_score works all the time
    scores = cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, cv=kfold)
    print('mean score: ' + str(np.mean((scores))))
    # relative importance
    importances = estimator.feature_importances_
    print(' importances: ' + str(importances))
    return np.mean(scores), importances, kfold

def confuse(X, y, estimator, aug):
    accuracy, importances, kfold = cross_val(X, y, estimator, aug)
    pred = cross_val_predict(estimator, X, y, cv=kfold)
    labels = sorted(list(set(y)))
    confusion = np.float32(confusion_matrix(y_true=y, y_pred=pred, labels=labels))
```

Comment: Of course this is not a solution, but a workaround:
I fitted and predicted with each fold independently and then averaged the results. This works, but since there exists such a method I expect it to work. Does someone else have similar problems?